# Order UI-GRID Records By Relevance

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[image]

In this image/example (its not mine, but is the same idea), if you search by "S" letter, it will bring 3 records. So, i want to show these records ordered by relevance. 
In this particular case, the results that i wish are: 
Sleeping \ Basktball \ Thermal

Anyone has some tips or direction to help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define relevance or find a way to calc it according to some defined metric.

Add relevance as a field of the row.

Add something similar to the element that has the ng-repeat directive:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in things | orderBy:relevance ">
```

Check the example here [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)